# Separability of $L^p$ space: general proof.

Tags: measure-theory, reference-request, proof-writing

I am studying the separability of $L^p$ spaces, where $p\in [1,+\infty)$. On the texts I am reading it is shown only that the $L^p(\mathbb{R},\mathcal{L}(\mathbb{R}),\lambda)$, where $\lambda$ is the Lebesgue measure, or that $L^p(E,\mathcal{L}(\mathbb{R^n\cap E}),\lambda_n)$, where $E\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n$ ia an open subset with the usual topology spaces, are separable.

I'm looking for some text where something more general is said: for example:

> Let $(X,\mathcal{A},\mu)$ a measure space such that:
>
> $(i)\;$ the measurable space $(X,\mathcal{A})$ is [separable](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/817297/connection-between-separable-measure-spaces-and-sigma-finite-measure-spaces?rq=1);
>
> $(ii)\;$ the measure $\mu$ is $\sigma-$ finite;
> then for each $p\in [1,\infty)$ the $L^p(X,\mathcal{A},\mu)$ is separable.

Also I would need an example whereby if you assume that the measure $\mu$ is not $\sigma-$ finite then don't make the statement.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Separability is a topological notion. do you mean that $X$ is a topological space that is separable and the sigma algebra $\mathcal{A}$ is that of the Borel sets?

Comment: @JustDroppedIn No, $X$ is a general set, and $\mathcal{A}$ a generic sigma algebra on $X$.

Comment: So how do you mean $X$ is separable?

Comment: @JustDroppedIn I don't know, sorry. I know there is a general result as I wrote in the post, but I don't know if there are further hypotheses.

Comment: In the setting of Lebesgue Caratheodory, If the ambient $\sigma$--algebra, $\mathcal{A}$ in your notation,  is countably generated, i.e., there is a countable set $\mathcal{C}$ such that $\sigma(\mathcal{C})=\mathcal{S}$, and the measure $\mu$ is $\sigma$--finite, then the $L_p$ spaces ($1\leq p<\infty$) are separable.

Comment: @OliverDiaz Yes, you are right. But I'm looking for a text in which these things are written precisely and formally.

Comment: In the setting of Daniel, if in the  elementary integral $(\mathcal{E},I)$,  $\mathcal{E}$ is separable in the uniform norm,  then the $L_p$ spaces $1\leq p<\infty$ are separable.

Comment: I can't remember a precise textbook where that is written as such. I think I learned these thingsas exercises in a book of Markov Chins by Meyn & Tweedie. Perhaps, Folland's took has these facts as excersices. It is enough to show that simple functions are separable (there is a countable set of simple functions that is dense in the space of simple functions in the $L_1$ norm) given the assumptions of  $\mathcal{A}$ being countably generated...

Comment: Check this: unfortunately Breziz mentions the theorem as you want it with a proof only for $\mathbb{R}$, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/878948/proof-of-separability-of-lp-spaces/1744132

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a counter example to separability of $L_p$ ($1\leq p<\infty$) consider the real line with the co-countable $\sigma$-algebra ($A$ is measurable if either $A$ is countable or $\mathbb{R}\setminus A$ is countable). This is space is not even $\sigma$--finite.

---

A set of notes where one can see things written formally and precisely (in the words of the OP) is chapter 5 in

[https://people.tamu.edu/~t-schlumprecht/course_notes_math655_23c.pdf](https://people.tamu.edu/%7Et-schlumprecht/course_notes_math655_23c.pdf)

The author shows that under the conditions stated in the OP, the space $L_p(\mu)$ is isometrically isomorphic to $L_p[0,1]\oplus\ell_p(I)$ for some countable set $I$. In addition, if there $\mu$ has no atoms, then $L_p$ is isometrically isomorphic to $L_p[0,1]$. The desired conclusion of the OP will follow from here as step functions with rational coefficients and rational closed intervals as bases are dense. **This is a big result! It gives you more than what you asked for**.

---

If the space $\mathcal{A}$ is countable generated and the measure $\mu$ is finite, a simple direct proof to the separability of $L_p$ ($1\leq p<\infty$) can be derived with our resorting to the strong result of Schlump. Here is a **sketch of a proof:**

- It suffices to assume $\mu$ is finite.
- Suppose $\mathcal{C}=\{C_n:n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ generates $\mathcal{A}$. Define $\mathcal{A}_n$ to be the algebra generated by $\{C_1,\ldots,C_n\}$. Each $\mathcal{A}_n$ is finite; hence $\hat{A}=\bigcup_n\mathcal{A}_n$ is a countable algebra that generates $\mathcal{A}$.
- construct the outer measure $\mu^*(E)=\inf\{\sum_n\mu(A_n): A_n\in\hat{\mathcal{A}}, ,E\subset\bigcup_nA_n\}$. The procedure of Carathéodory will produce a complete measure that extends $\mu$ to a larger $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{M}\supset\mathcal{A}$
- From this construction, you can see that any measurable set can be approximate by sets in $\hat{\mathcal{A}}$, that is $(X,\mathcal{M})$ is separable.
- The conclusion follows by taking rational linear combinations of sets (indicator functions rather) in $\hat{\mathcal{A}}$.

---

**Edit:** I just learned that this question, not surprisingly, has been addressed before in [this site](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1447055/space-mathcallpx-sigma-mu-is-separable-iff-sigma-rho-delta-i). The proof is more pedestrian compared to the much stronger result in Schlump's notes, for the former works under the assumption that $(X,\mu)$ is separable, and the later works under the assumption that $\mathcal{A}$ is countably generated. Countably generated $\mathcal{S}$ implies separability of $(X,\mathcal{S})$ (but that requires a proof, which I furnished above).

Comment: where is the finiteness of $\mu$ used

Comment: @somitra: In that each $A\in \mathcal{A}$ is integrable. For the general $\sigma$--algebra, one first partition the ambient space $X$ as a countable union of pairwise disjoint sets in $\mathcal{A}$, say $X=\bigcup_nX_n$. Then apply the finite case result to $(X,\mathcal{A},\mathbb{1}_{X_n}\cdot\mu)$

Comment: Are we using $\pi-\lambda$ theorem for claiming that caratheodiry's procedure leads to an extension of orginal measure. Don't we need $\{C_1,C_2,...,C_n,...\}$ to be a $\pi-system$

Comment: @somita: $hat{\mathcal{A}}$ is a $\pi$-system. In ant case, we don't need Doob's theorem. The construction of the outer measures and the extension of the measure design by Carathéodory is done without requiring any monotone class theorems.

Comment: I have a doubt regarding the construction of outer measure. Why do we consider unions of $A \in \hat{\mathcal{A}}$ instead of simply sets belonging to the set-algebra while taking infinimum.

Comment: They have to be at most  countable unions. In Carathéodory's construction, for any set $E\subset X$, define 
$$\mu^*(E)=\inf\{\sum_n\mu(A_n): E\subset\bigcup_nA_n,\, \{A_n:n\in\mathbb{N}\}\subset\hat{\mathcal{A}}\}$$

Comment: It would seem that the first provided link no longer works? I'm getting a 404 error.

Comment: @BrunoB: see chapter 5 [here](https://people.tamu.edu/~t-schlumprecht/course_notes_math655_23c.pdf). Unfortunately, as people retire, content in websites may cease to exists.