# Proving that $C_c(U)$ is separable with respect to $\|\cdot\|_p$

Tags: functional-analysis

> Let $p \in [1,\infty)$ and let $U \subset \mathbb{R}^d$ be open. Prove that $C_c(U$) is separable with respect to $\|\cdot\|_p$.

I think I only need to show that $C_c(U)$ is separable with respect to $\|·\|_\infty$ ($C_c(U),\|\cdot\|_p$) as a subspace is separable.

Comment: Try explaining what you have tried and where you got stuck. It may also be helpful to know from where you got the question. Oh, and welcome to MathExchange.

Answer (score 0):

The statement of the problem may be proved directly as follows

- Clearly $C_c(U)\subset L_p(U)$, for if $f\in C_c(U)$ and $K=\operatorname{supp}(f)$, then
  $$\|f\|_p\leq\Big(\lambda(K)\Big)^{1/p}\|f\|^{1/p}_\infty<\infty$$
- $L_p(U)$ $1\leq p<\infty$ is separable itself  since the Borel $\sigma$-algebra on $U$ is countably generated (a explanation about countably generated $\sigma$ algebras and separability of $L_p$ can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3742577/121671)).
- Being $L_p$  a separable normed space,  any subspace (in the topological sense) inherits the separability property; hence  $C_c(U)$ with the $L_p$ norm is separable.

---

Comment: Any subspace with the subspace topology will be separable, but $C_c(U)$ has an entirely different topology. For example the space of all bounded functions is contained in $L_p(U)$ for bounded $U$, but if we equip it with the topology generated by the supremum norm it is not separable.

Comment: @K.Power: The OP refers to the topology on $C_c(U)$ inherited by $L_p(U)$

Comment: Ahh I see that the OP has made a typo. In the main question the talk about the subspace topology, but in their next line they talk about the uniform topology.

Comment: @K.Power: Actually, the OP wanted to use the separability of $C_c(U)$ if $\|\;\|_\infty$ to prove separability in $L_p$. That strategy works too, but it requires some control over supports of approximations via bump functions. It is my view that a more direct proof using the properties of $L_p$ is easier and more instructive.